# Wrong SELECT output with SQLite3 and Swift

Tags: swift, database, sqlite

I have a task to make a mobile app in Swift to store data about students. When entering the app, the database should be created. There should be a text field, from which a user can insert his name into the database, and a button to reload the page and look at all the names in DB. Also, the date of creation should be stored in the database.
I have the following code:

```
import UIKit
import SQLite3

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    var db: OpaquePointer?
    var Students = [Student]()

    @IBOutlet weak var textFieldName: UITextField!
    @IBAction func buttonSave(_ sender: UIButton) {
        //getting values from textfields
        let name = textFieldName.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        let d = Date()
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"
        let date = formatter.string(from: d)

        //validating that values are not empty
        if(name?.isEmpty)!{
            textFieldName.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
            return
        }

        //creating a statement
        var stmt: OpaquePointer?

        //the insert query
        let queryString = "INSERT INTO Students (name, date) VALUES (?,?)"

        //preparing the query
        if sqlite3_prepare(db, queryString, -1, &stmt, nil) != SQLITE_OK{
            let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
            print("error preparing insert: \(errmsg)")
            return
        }

        //binding the parameters
        if sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, name, -1, nil) != SQLITE_OK{
            let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
            print("failure binding name: \(errmsg)")
            return
        }

        if sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, date, -1, nil) != SQLITE_OK{
            let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
            print("failure binding date: \(errmsg)")
            return
        }

        //executing the query to insert values
        if sqlite3_step(stmt) != SQLITE_DONE {
            let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
            print("failure inserting student: \(errmsg)")
            return
        }

        //emptying the textfields
        textFieldName.text=""
        readValues()

        //displaying a success message
        print("Student saved successfully")
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var tableViewStudents: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let fileURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
            .appendingPathComponent("StudentsDatabase.sqlite")

        if sqlite3_open(fileURL.path, &db) != SQLITE_OK {
            print("error opening database")
        }

        if sqlite3_exec(db, "DROP TABLE Students", nil, nil, nil) != SQLITE_OK {
            let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
            print("error deleting table: \(errmsg)")
        }

        if sqlite3_exec(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Students (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT, date TEXT)", nil, nil, nil) != SQLITE_OK {
            let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
            print("error creating table: \(errmsg)")
        }

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return Students.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        let student: Student
        student = Students[indexPath.row]
        print(student.name)
        cell.textLabel?.text = student.name
        return cell
    }

    func readValues(){
        //first empty the list of heroes
        Students.removeAll()

        //this is our select query
        let queryString = "SELECT * FROM Students"

        //statement pointer
        var stmt:OpaquePointer?

        //preparing the query
        if sqlite3_prepare(db, queryString, -1, &stmt, nil) != SQLITE_OK{
            let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
            print("error preparing select: \(errmsg)")
            return
        }

        //traversing through all the records
        while(sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW){
            let id = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 0)
            let name = String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 1))
            let date = String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 2))

            //adding values to list
            Students.append(Student(id: Int(id), name: String(name), date: String(date)))
        }
        tableViewStudents.reloadData()
    }
}

class Student {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var date: String

    init(id: Int, name: String, date: String){
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.date = date
    }
}
```

The thing is, for some reason the name of a student doesn't appear in the table. Instead, only a slice of date is shown, sliced by the number of letters in the name of a student. So if I try to insert "John" on the 18th of May, it will return "18.0" - 4 symbols picked from the date.
Any help on how to fix this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary issue is that you use `String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 1)` to read the stored string but you write the string using a simple reference to your `String` variable instead of using something like `name.utf8CString`. Update each of your `sqlite3_bind_text` calls.

There are a few other issues in your code that need to be fixed:

1. Never use `SELECT * FROM`. There's no guarantee the fields will be returned in a specific order. List the fields so the column index you pass to `sqlite3_column_xxx` is known to match.
2. You never call `sqlite3_finalize` on the prepared statement in `buttonSave` and `readValues`. And you will need to refactor your code to ensure you finalize the prepared statement even if other code gives an error.
3. Your `Student` class should probably be a `struct`. Then you don't even need to provide the `init` explicitly.
4. Variable names should start with lowercase letters. Change `Students` to `students`.
5. In your `buttonSave` method, check the validity of `name` sooner. No sense in creating and formatting the date if the name isn't valid.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer.